# Parsing Complex JSON File Into Batch

Tags: json, batch-file

I have a batch file which is obtained via a webrequest. It basically looks like this

```
[
    {
        "status": "CANCELLED",
        "username": "tj_cj8810",
        "otherdata": "some other data"
    },
    {
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "username": "silvose281",
        "otherdata": "some other data"
    },
    {
        "status": "CANCELLED",
        "username": "metzgerrr",
        "otherdata": "some other data"
    },
    {
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "username": "haruki1337",
        "otherdata": "some other data"
    }
]
```

I need to search this file based on a username and return the status or return NOTFOUND if its not in the file. I need to do this in a batch file. How do I go about reading this data in a batch file.

Comment: Fundamentally, `for /f "delims=" %%b in (filename) do echo %%b` .

Comment: Parsing JSON is one of those rare times that I'll recommend using Powershell. That said, this JSON isn't even remotely complex and you could probably parse it pretty easily with a `for /f` loop.

Comment: Well, if you simply want to see not found or found, then no need to use `for` loops. `findstr "tj_cj8830" "FILENAME.json" && echo Found || echo Not Found`